# Is it possible to change Swift String Interpolation for the String typealias?

Tags: swift, string-interpolation, swift-string, customstringconvertible

I have a lot of DTOs in my app which log some field. That field should not be logged because the data is kind of sensitive.
The model looks like this:

```
typealias HiddenFieldType = String

struct DTO1 {
    var field1_1: String
    var fieldToHide: HiddenFieldType
    var field1_2: String
    var field1_3: String
}

struct DTO2 {
    var field2_1: String
    var field2_2: String
    var fieldToHide: HiddenFieldType
    var field2_3: String
}
```

the code which outputs the data is like this (actually it's `os_log` in a real app):

```
func test() {
    let dto1 = DTO1(field1_1: "1_1", fieldToHide: "super-secret-1", field1_2: "1_2", field1_3: "1_3")
    let dto2 = DTO2(field2_1: "2_1", field2_2: "2_2", fieldToHide: "super-secret-2", field2_3: "2_3")

    print("Test1: dto1=\(dto1) dto2=\(dto2)")
}
```

---

#### Approach #1

It seems the field can be hidden in DTO1 with such code:

```
extension String.StringInterpolation {
    mutating func appendInterpolation(_ value: DTO1) {
        appendInterpolation("field1_1: \(value.field1_1), fieldToHide: ‍♀️, field1_2: \(value.field1_2), field1_3: \(value.field1_3)")
    }
}
```

However, the solution is neither scalable nor maintainable:

- the same extension should be added for each DTO
- each field should be included into `appendInterpolation` - a lot of boilerplate
- if a new field is added to some DTO, we may forget to update `appendInterpolation` etc

---

#### Approach #2

I tried to add interpolation for `HiddenFieldType` (assuming it's a type, just like `DTO1`...):

```
extension String.StringInterpolation {
    mutating func appendInterpolation(_ value: HiddenFieldType) {
        appendInterpolation("‍♀️")
    }
}
```

But this solution doesn't work at all:

- the compiler says "Function call causes an infinite recursion"
- and it actually causes an infinite recursion
- when changing `appendInterpolation` to `appendLiteral`, there's no recursion, but "super-secret-1" is not hidden

---

#### Approach #3

I tried overriding `DefaultStringInterpolation`, conforming to `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`/`ExpressibleByStringInterpolation`, but it doesn't work: the compiler says that `HiddenFieldType` is `String`, and `Conformance of 'String' to protocol 'ExpressibleByStringLiteral' was already stated in the type's module 'Swift'`

The only approach I can imagine is changing `typealias HiddenFieldType = String` to `struct HiddenFieldType { let value: String }`, so the `HiddenFieldType` becomes a "real" type.

---

#### Approach #4

Then such code doesn't cause an infinite recursion anymore, but doesn't works either (the value is unhidden)

```
struct HiddenFieldType { 
    let value: String 
}

extension String.StringInterpolation {
    mutating func appendInterpolation(_ value: HiddenFieldType) {
        appendInterpolation("‍♀️")
    }
}
```

---

#### Approach #5

This code finally works:

```
struct HiddenFieldType { 
    let value: String 
}

extension HiddenFieldType: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        "‍♀️"
    }
}
```

As I can't imagine any better, for now I'd use this approach, but it also has some slight scalability issues, as I must update each `DTO`'s initializing point:
from

```
let dto1 = DTO1(field1_1: "1_1", fieldToHide: "super-secret-1", field1_2: "1_2", field1_3: "1_3")
```

to

```
let dto1 = DTO1(field1_1: "1_1", fieldToHide: .init(value: "super-secret-1"), field1_2: "1_2", field1_3: "1_3")
```

and I hoped to only add some extension in the file which contains `typealias HiddenFieldType = String`, and not to update the entire code.

---

#### The questions

- Is it possible to hide the value of `HiddenFieldType` without changing it from `typealias` to `struct`, and without updating each `DTO`?
- Is there any better approach than 5?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you mentioned that this is actually `os_log`. Isn't this whole question baked into `os_log` via the `privacy` parameter? (At a minimum look at OSLogMessage, which seems to address exactly what you're describing, exactly by not using String since you can't modify how String works.)

Comment: @RobNapier thanks! If I understand you correctly, we can change `print("dto=\(dto)` tp `os_log("dto=\(dto, privacy: .private)`. But in case the privacy of whole DTO is affected, and I want to hide only a specific field. Moreover, each DTO should conform to `CustomStringConvertible`, which is no better than `Approach #1`. Or do you know some way to specify a privacy level only for a one field in `os_log("dto=\(dto, privacy: .private)`?

Comment: Ah, now I'm seeing your question more clearly. #5 is a good solution; you just want to implement ExpressibleByStringLiteral to avoid reworking your code anywhere you have used literals. As WongWray notes, a typealias does literally nothing in Swift except improve reability. It  creates an alias for the name that is swapped in before the types are evaluated. It will also likely be handy to implement LosslessStringConvertible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to hide the value of HiddenFieldType without changing it from typealias to struct

I think you're attempting to use the wrong tool for the job here. A `typealias` is just a name change, and it sounds like you want something that acts fundamentally different than a `String` (i.e. one gets printed when passed into an `os_log` call and one doesn't). You won't be able to write logic that treats a `String` different from its `typealias`; the compiler doesn't differentiate between them.

Is it possible to make your `DTO`s classes instead of structs? (EDIT: see below, you can keep them as structs and just use a protocol extension) If so, you could use reflection on a superclass to accomplish this without having to manually specify the `description` for every different DTO.

```
struct HiddenFieldType {
    let value: String
}

open class DTO: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        Mirror(reflecting: self).children.compactMap { $0.value as? String }.joined(separator: "\n")
    }
}

final class DTO1: DTO {
    let field1_1: String
    let field1_2: String
    let fieldToHide: HiddenFieldType

    init(field1_1: String, field1_2: String, fieldToHide: HiddenFieldType) {
        self. field1_1 = field1_1
        self. field1_2 = field1_2
        self. fieldToHide = fieldToHide
    }
}
```

Note that I'm including all Strings in the `description` but, if you have types other than `String` and `HiddenFieldType` that you want to log, you could always just `filter` out the `HiddenFieldType`s specifically.

Personally, I'd be hesitant to rely on reflection for any critical code but other people have more tolerance for it so its a judgement call.

**EDIT**:
You don't need to use inheritance to accomplish this. Instead of a superclass, `DTO` should be a protocol that conforms to `CustomStringConvertible`:

```
protocol DTO: CustomStringConvertible {}
extension DTO {
    public var description: String {
        Mirror(reflecting: self).children.compactMap { $0.value as? String }.joined(separator: "\n")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach with the reflection! I've finally chosen approach #5. I'm marking your answer as accepted because formally you've explained that it's not possible to differentiate `String` from typealias.